# Update akka cluster entry points data

Tags: scala, concurrency, cluster-computing, akka, spray

I am working on a system that utilizes an Akka cluster. The dilemma that I am facing is how to update data on entry points. I have the following structure:

> [Load Balancer] -> [Entry Point](spray powered) -> [Workers]

On the entry point I need to keep a list of users that are allowed to access data, in other words I need to keep a list with, let's say emails. However this list has to be updated frequently when new users are authorized or removed.

What would be the best approach to tackle this problem? I was thinking about just switching this container of e-mails/IDs to a mutable one, but then the question is whether the system will lock this data on event processing and how this affects performance.

Any recommendations would be great!

Update:
- distribution of a new user will be done via a regular spray rest request. From the outside authorized for such system requests request will be made with security keys and a user ID to be added to the list
- there are multiple nodes, each has spray rest entry point
- speed doesn't matter as long as it is a couple seconds
- order doesn't matter.

The system will just a get a message on load balancer that it has to add one more ID to the list of users. Because of load balancer it will end up on one of the entry point spray nodes. It has to update it's own list of IDs and also broad cast to all other entry points in the app(basically all from the load balancer list) the required update.

Hope this clarifies better.

Comment: I think you need to expand a bit on how your system is going to work. Is the question about how to distribute (updates to) the authorization list? What component is overseeing the update and on which node on the cluster does it run? What are the kind of guarantees you need for the update (as it is a racy operation), i.e. how fast must the update to the authorization list propagate, do you need a strict ordering in which a user is always permitted access once the access was granted, or is it ok if the permit is only eventually available after the update happened?

Comment: I have updated my question, please take a look once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is a first draft.

Every spray endpoints must have the same "view" of the access list otherwise your requests could be refused depending on which endpoint they are a balanced to.

Therefore you need to have a referent with the official access list so you can recover from a crash and/or create a new spray node with an up-to-date access list.

You could create a [singleton actor](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/contrib/cluster-singleton.html) in your akka-cluster that would be responsible for reading and updating the access list from a persistent store.

Then using the [distributed akka pub/sub extension](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/contrib/distributed-pub-sub.html) you could create a distributed message bus where :

- all the spray endpoints and the singleton actor as well subscribe to the channel "access update" for example. That way all the actors can keep their access list "synchronized".
- when a spray endpoint received a request for adding or removing a user/access, it pushes a notification on the channel "access update". Every spray endpoints can update their access list and so the singleton update the persistent list in the store.

What do you think?

Comment: Sounds good until I try :) Another question, this sounds like a plan but what about the storage of such a list. It has to be var, does it affect performance if it is a var? In other words, if it is just read would there be also a lock in the system or it will work just fine until there is a write lock?

Comment: See this about var  performace for state http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808159/alternatives-to-using-var-for-state-with-actors. You should not worry about lock but about update access propagation.